# Linux - Delete lines from file 1 in file 2 BIG DATA

Tags: linux

have two files:

```
file1:
a
b
c
d

file2:
a
b
f
c
d
e

output file (file2) should be:
f
e
```

I want that the lines of file1 should be deleted directly in file2. I want that the output should be not a new file. It should direct deleted in file 2. Of course there can be created a temp file.
I real file two contains more than 300.000 lines. That is the reason why some solution:

```
comm -13 file1 file2
```

don't work.

Answer (score 1):

`comm` needs the input files to be sorted. You can use process substitution for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > tmp_file
mv tmp_file > original_file
```

Output:

```
e
f
```

Alternatively, if you have enough memory, you can use the following `awk` command which does not need the input to be sorted:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

Output (preserved sort order):

```
f
e
```

Keep in mind that the size of the array `a` directly depends on the size of `file1`.

PS: `grep -vFf file1 file2` can also be used and the memory requirements are the same as for the `awk` solution. Given that, I would probably just use `grep`.

Comment: In all solutions nothing is changed in file2! All lines which should be deleted are there anymore!

Comment: you need to save results to a temporary file and then move that temporary file to file2. I showed that in the `comm` example

Comment: No is has no effect on the result! Also with temp file nothing will be changed in file2! There must be a solution for big files! Is there no solution with sed posssible?

Comment: Can you stop using exclamation marks and think for a moment? I showed how to do it many times: `command file1 file2 > temp_file` then `mv temp_file file2`